# How to show next date using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have an example

```
id  projectid     date
1       2     2015-04-19 
2       2     2015-04-19 
3       2     2015-04-19 
4       2     2015-04-19 
5       2     2015-04-21 
6       2     2015-04-21 
7       2     2015-04-21 
8       2     2015-04-22 
9       2     2015-04-22 
10      2     2015-04-22
```

I want to show next upcoming stored date using `2015-04-19` date, i.e next date is `2015-04-21`, using mysql query

```
id  projectid     date
5       2     2015-04-21 
6       2     2015-04-21 
7       2     2015-04-21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE `date` = (SELECT `date` FROM table 
                WHERE `date`>'2015-04-19' ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateAdd Function in Select Statement like below

```
DATEADD(d,1,(CASE table.date as Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically to display next date older than 2015-04-19 from your database, this should be enough:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2015-04-19' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Correct, except you forgot to add `ORDER BY date`, otherwise you need to be sure that dates in a table are indeed in a sorted sequence. Check my answer.

Comment: Ah that's true! I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2015-04-19' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE**

You wrote that you want to *show next upcoming stored date*, but looking at your example output and your comment it looks like you want to get all records with the next date.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=(
    SELECT date FROM table WHERE date > '2015-04-19' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
)
```

[SQL Fiffle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bc4e/1/0), use it as a copy paste solution.

Comment: above query displays one record only i.e, 2015-04-21, i want to display total records of 21 date

Comment: Updated. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Sub query will return the next date from which results will come according to that date only.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date=("SELECT date FROM table WHERE date > '2015-04-19' ORDER BY date LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Ok @Reeno. I will edit it. and, from the next time i will keep in mind. Ok. Cheers.